# css style is not working added via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below is my code....

I have four divs with spans with specific text, while running the below query only the last div span is getting orange color

```
function populateFavorites(result) {       
    $.each(result, function (key, res) {              
        var data = {
            "ISO": res.CurveIsoCode, "Utility": res.CurveUtility, "PriceDifference": 2,
            "Price": 5, "DefaultTerm": res.Term, "StartDate": formatDate(res.StartDate), "DefaultPeakPriceType": res.PeakPriceTypeName,
            "ChartControl": res.FavouritesId, "ChekBoxID": res.FavouritesId
        };

        isoGridData.push(data);
        $("#gridtarget").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: isoGridData,
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#iso-utility-detail").html())
        });

        GraphValues(res.CurveIsoCode, res.CurveUtility, res.PeakPriceTypeName, formatDate(res.StartDate), res.Term,
                _historyType, _Url,
                priceValues, priceDates, "ChartControl" + res.FavouritesId,
                0, 10, 10);

        $("#idcontentgrid" + res.FavouritesId + " span:contains(" + res.HistoryTypeName + ")").css('color', 'orange');
    });
}
```

Any idea why it is? and how to apply for all the div spans?

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the html it's hard to say, but I suspect your selector ($("#idcontentgrid" + res.FavouritesId + " span:contains(" + res.HistoryTypeName + ")")) isn't selecting the other spans you're interested in.

Comment: Are you able to step through the code? Is res.FavouritesId the value you expect it to be?

Comment: Please review how to create a [mcve]. Currently there is not enough information in the question to be able to answer it.

Comment: $("#idcontentgrid" + res.FavouritesId + " span:contains(" + res.HistoryTypeName + ")").css('color', 'orange'); is selecting the other four div spans too (I checked in the chrome developer console), but after each loop it is vanishing and at last only the last div span color will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from your question each time your loop works, the css you are applying are getting overrided by kendo grid.

So try removing your logic to apply css in a separate loop like this,

```
function populateFavorites(result) {       
    $.each(result, function (key, res) {              
        //existing code
        GraphValues(res.CurveIsoCode, res.CurveUtility, res.PeakPriceTypeName, formatDate(res.StartDate), res.Term,
                _historyType, _Url,
                priceValues, priceDates, "ChartControl" + res.FavouritesId,
                0, 10, 10);

    });

    $.each(result, function (key, res) {              
       $("#idcontentgrid" + res.FavouritesId + " span:contains(" + res.HistoryTypeName + ")").css('color', 'orange');           
    });
}
```